# Error: from matplotlib import _png ImportError: cannot import name '_png' from 'matplotlib' (C:\\Garden\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py)

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy

I want work with `garden.matplotlib.FigureCanvas`, but I get every time same problem. I install `matplotlib`, `garden` and `kivy` (separate). All the Library installs work, except `matplotlib.backend_kivyagg`.
I downloaded a file from `kivy` for testing (https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.matplotlib).
Here the Error:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/alidi/OneDrive/Desktop/Garden/garden.matplotlib/garden.matplotlib-master/examples/test_backend.py", line 10, in <module>
     from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvas,\
   File "C:\Users\alidi\Desktop\Data_analysis_book_\Garden\lib\site-packages\kivy\garden\__init__.py", line 180, in load_module
     return self._load_module(fullname, moddir)
   File "C:\Users\alidi\Desktop\Data_analysis_book_\Garden\lib\site-packages\kivy\garden\__init__.py", line 183, in _load_module
     mod = imp.load_module(fullname, None, moddir,
   File "C:\Users\alidi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\imp.py", line 244, in load_module
     return load_package(name, filename)
   File "C:\Users\alidi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\imp.py", line 216, in load_package
     return _load(spec)
   File "C:\Users\alidi\.kivy\garden\garden.matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
     from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivy import FigureCanvasKivy,\
   File "C:\Users\alidi\.kivy\garden\garden.matplotlib\backend_kivy.py", line 256, in <module>
     from matplotlib import _png
 ImportError: cannot import name '_png' from 'matplotlib' (C:\Users\alidi\Desktop\Data_analysis_book_\Garden\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What version of matpotlib have you got installed?

Comment: How do you install the packages? Do you use `conda` or `pip`?

Comment: i use version 3.3.1

Comment: i install alle with pip install and work with pycharm

Comment: I'm pretty sure Kivy doesn't work with Python 3.8 yet (at least not via pypi: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6563), only 3.7 and lower so that would be a start. Let me just check my version of matplotlib and see if 3.3 works.

Comment: Use python 3.8.2

Comment: I'm pretty sure when i installed matplotlib 3.3 it didn't work either so i had to reinstall to a previous version, i'm currently running matplotlib 3.1.1 and python 3.7.3 and everything is running perfectly, when i attempted with the new versions (python 3.8+ and matplotlib 3.3+) i had no luck. I recommend installing both to previous versions and trying again.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem with python 3.7, kivy==2.0.0, kivy-garden==0.1.4, matplotlib==3.4.1.
Downgrading the matplotlib solved the problem:

```
pip install matplotlib==3.1.1
```